# Change format of money Postgresql

Tags: php, format, currency

I have a Postgre DB and one of these values are money (type, ofc).
When I do the Select using PHP, the output of that query is in this format:

Example: €1,00

I'm looking for something to change this format to this other:

Example: 1,00€.

What can I change in my query to get last one result?

Thanks!

Comment: you could xhange the way you are asking a question on stack overflow by looking at the FAQ section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way in PHP is to use str_replace :)

```
$cash = '€1,00';
$cash = str_replace('€','',$cash) . '€';
echo $cash;
```

But a better option is to change your DB field type to some numeric type and just to add the ' €' sign where you want it..

- You may do this replace inside your DB SELECT statement but I think that its better to do that inside your PHP..

Answer (score 1):

If its stored in database just like a number without currency you could just use function `number_format($x,y,'.','')`

where 
$x is your number
y is number of numbers behind decimal separator
'.' - means decimal separator is .
'' -means there is no separator between thousands

so u just format your number in a way u want and add "euro" sign.

if its price there is a function called money format :

u must use it with locales of country the currency u want fe. :

`setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE');
        echo money_format('%.2n', $your_variable);`

this means u use currency of germany. '%.2n' means your output is from $yourvariable and have 2 decimalnumbers

And to the thing of 'euro' sign after or before number. It depends of locales. I think slovak or spanish has euro sign after number.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you what you need, and be flexible across all currencies:

```
$value = '$4265';

if (!is_numeric($value[0])) {
    $value = substr($value, 1) . $value[0];    
}
```